# No Parameters are passed to SelectTemplate() of custom DataTemplateSelector. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm using a `CellTemplateSelector` to conditionally display a checkmark in a DataGrid Column.

The method `SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)` of my `DataTemplateSelector` class is called but the parameter item is null instead of the expected `DataRowView`-object.

Here is the XAML-Code. Items in Property `ItemsSource` of DataGrid is a `DataTable`, which works fine for the other columns. (*I work with Visual Studio Express 2010*)

```
...
<Window.Resources>        
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckedTemplate">
            <Path Width="16" Height="16" Margin="6,0,0,0" 
            x:Name="CheckMark" SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
            Stroke="Green" Fill="Green" StrokeThickness="1"
            Data="M 12.4227,0.00012207C 12.4867,0.126587 12.5333,0.274536 
            12.6787,0.321411C 9.49199,3.24792 6.704,6.57336 
            4.69865,10.6827C 4.04399,11.08 3.47066,11.5573 2.83199,
            11.9706C 2.09467,10.2198 1.692,8.13196 3.8147e-006,
            7.33606C 0.500004,6.79871 1.31733,6.05994 1.93067,6.2428C 
            2.85999,6.51868 3.14,7.9054 3.60399,8.81604C 5.80133,
            5.5387 8.53734,2.19202 12.4227,0.00012207 Z " />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="UncheckedTemplate">
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:CheckmarkTemplateSelector x:Key="CheckmarkTemplateSelector"  CheckedTemplate="{StaticResource CheckedTemplate}" UncheckedTemplate="{StaticResource UncheckedTemplate}" />
    </Window.Resources>
...
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">            
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="No" Binding="{Binding no}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selected" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CheckmarkTemplateSelector}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
...
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure it's always passed null, or just the first time?  The `CellTemplateSelector` is called once with a null `item` when setting up the logical tree, then called once per data item with `item` passed the bound object.  You may just be failing on the first null.

See also this question: [Why is the SelectTemplate Method run 2 times in debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534339/why-is-the-selecttemplate-method-run-2-times-in-debug-mode)

Comment: Your are right. It's only the first time null. Didn't know that and got stucked on the null value. But there was another error, I have fixed now. Now it works. Thanks a lot, this really helped me!